# What does turtle.Screen() actually do?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I decided to create a small game with interface created with only `turtle`, but I can't understand what `turtle.Screen()` actually does. I searched the internet and didn't find an answer to my question anywhere except for docs, but the explanation is unclear to me.

I want somebody to explain me why I need to initialize a var with `turtle.Screen()` object. I understood that it is not a class, but it tells me only that "it is not a class".

I experimented with that a bit and didn't find any need to use it. Only if I want to get all the `turtle.Turtle()`s from the current screen, but I also can't see any practical application to this.

I thought, "Maybe it creates another screen", but this program:

```
import turtle
sc1 = turtle.Screen()
turtle.forward(100)
sc2 = turtle.Screen()
turtle.backward(100)
turtle.done()
```

has only one screen.

I also clean the window through `turtle.clear()`. If I want to use several brushes (turtles), I can do that without creating a `Screen()`. If I want to adjust the window size, I can do that without `Screen()`.

So what does `turtle.Screen()` actually do? Not what it is, but what it does.

Comment: [_"The function `Screen()` returns a singleton object of a `TurtleScreen` subclass. This function should be used when `turtle` is used as a standalone tool for doing graphics."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)

Comment: What is standalone tool... Is it when I use it as a part of another program or when it is the whole program or what?

Comment: Turtle can be used *standalone* (self contained program) via `Turtle` and `Screen` but it also can be used *embedded* in a tkinter program using `RawTurtle` and `TurtleScreen`.  When embedded, you can set up multiple turtle windows, and/or multiple turtle canvases within the same window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)

> The TurtleScreen class defines graphics windows as a playground for the drawing turtles. Its constructor needs a tkinter.Canvas or a ScrolledCanvas as argument. It should be used when turtle is used as part of some application.

> The function Screen() returns a singleton object of a TurtleScreen subclass. This function should be used when turtle is used as a standalone tool for doing graphics. As a singleton object, inheriting from its class is not possible.

> All methods of TurtleScreen/Screen also exist as functions, i.e. as part of the procedure-oriented interface.

I agree the architecture of the module can be a bit confusing for newcomers. I will assume you have *some basic* understanding of OOP, as this module is built on it.

There is a class `TurtleScreen`, which represents a window for turtles (you can read the details in the doc). You can create an instance of this class yourself using the constructor (needs a `tkinter.Canvas` or a `ScrolledCanvas`), which you should do when you use `turtle` as a part of a bigger project (for ex. adding a turtle canvas to a bigger `tkinter` app).

There is, however, a convenience method, `Screen()`. This creates and returns a `singleton` screen - so it creates the `TurtleScreen` instance for you (and also the  Canvas & tkinter window object). You have way less control over the creation of the `Screen` this way, so it's not useful in all scenarios, but it gets the job done if you are happy with the defaults, and only want one screen. The term `singleton` means that it only creates the `TurtleScreen` once, so if you call the function more than once, you get back the same object - so you can't have multiple screens this way.

To be even more <del>confusing</del> convenient, methods of the `TurtleScreen` (and other classes like `Turtle`) are also available as functions acting on the singleton instancess - i.e `bgcolor()` is actually the `bgcolor` method of `Screen` bound to the singleton instance, and `forward()` is also just calling the `forward()` method of the `Turtle` classes singleton instance.

This class-singleton-convenience function design can be quite confusing if you don't understand it's background, and is not that commonly used.

You can use

- the convenience functions if you just want to use one object of each class with their "basic settings"
- the singleton instances if you need a bit more control over them (in case some methods / properties are not "exported" as functions)
- or you can create your own instances if you need full control or you want to use more than one object.