# why input() is not blocking in this case?

Tags: python, input, python-turtle

so I have programmed a simple script that suppose to draw a shape based on an input.
as I know, input() is a blocking function which means it must wait for an input
before the code can run again.
but, it performs the next line before I even enter a value.
it makes no sense to me. why does it happen?

```
import turtle
import time


mouse = turtle.Turtle()

x = input()

turtle.Screen()

if x == "t":
    for i in range(3):
        mouse.fd(100)
        mouse.rt(120)

elif x == "c":
    mouse.circle(100)

else:
    mouse.bk(100)

time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by run again? There's no loop in this code, it just runs once. Try adding a prompt to the `input()` call so you know it's executing.

Comment: @Barmar - I believe they're saying that the `turtle.Screen` line of code is being ran before they have entered an input, "run again" here appears to be referring to "it must wait for an input before the code can continue"

Comment: by "run again" I mean, that the code must stop executing until I enter a value. and then, keep executing

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you accidentally typed an extra newline when you started the script, and that's being used as the input.

Comment: put `print(x)` on the line after `x=input()`

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by that?

Comment: @bn_ln it still doesn't work

Comment: @coolness, how do you decide that it execute `turtle.Screen()`? You can delete that line and it still will show the window with the turtle.

Comment: @buran yes you are right. I was not aware of this. then why is turtle.Screen good for?

Comment: @buran Ihave just looked in the actual constructor. it opens it by defult if I haven't done it by myself. Thank you I get it now

Comment: When you call `turtle.Turtle()` it draws on Screen created automatically, as stated in the docs. Check also [What does turtle.Screen() actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73174954/4046632)

Comment: `turtle.Screen()` ("the next line") does nothing on its own and certainly isn't running before `input()` is completed blocking, i.e. the user has entered something. You have to assign it to a variable and call methods on it for the screen to have any effect (or call those methods directly without a variable). Are you confused because `mouse = turtle.Turtle()` opens the turtle window? Maybe move `input()` above that.